# Configuring X-Forwarded-For Header in GKE nginx Proxy Configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, rackattack

I have installed an nginx controller in GKE (GCP) on a cluster and a rails app set up with a Rack Attack configuration for restricting access. We're having trouble getting the remote IP address of incoming requests. It keeps returning the ingress IP not the remote user's IP.  I've found [several mentions](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack/issues/139) of this issue in [various forms](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1000).  It mentions adding a setting to the nginx proxy config. Having installed the nginx controller using the standard public files on github, I don't know how to reconfigure the proxy on this controller. How would I apply a new proxy config to this setup?

See ingress controller yaml below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-04-30T15:45:32Z"
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
    chart: nginx-ingress-1.36.3
    component: controller
    heritage: Tiller
    release: nginx-ingress
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: nginx-ingress
  resourceVersion: "113532709"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/nginx-ingress/services/nginx-ingress-controller
  uid: a045e8e8-8af9-11ea-8a88-42010a030a07
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.163.8.100
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 30487
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - name: https
    nodePort: 32616
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    release: nginx-ingress
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: x.x.x.x
```

Comment: can you show your ngnix configuration?

Comment: That's actually a big part of my question so I'm not sure what you mean. I installed the nginx controller directly from the source files on github. i.e. (kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-0.32.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml).